# I am trying to mimic this page. but mine is showing black screen with "Click or tap to start video"

Tags: html, aframe, virtual-reality

https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/360-video/

I am new to Aframe js. So, I'm trying to mimic this page. I have copied whole code but still its is not working.

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" device-orientation-permission-ui="">
            <a-assets>
                
                <video id="video" autoplay="" loop="" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" src="https://bitmovin.com/player-content/playhouse-vr/progressive.mp4">
                </video>
            </a-assets>
            <a-videosphere rotation="0 -90 0" src="#video" play-on-click="" material="" geometry="" scale="">
            </a-videosphere>
            <a-camera camera="" position="" rotation="" look-controls="" wasd-controls="">
                <a-entity position="0 0 -1.5" text="align:center;
                                                    width:6;
                                                    wrapCount:100;
                                                    color: white;
                                                    value: Click or tap to start video" hide-on-play="#video">
                </a-entity>
            </a-camera>
            </a-scene>
        
        
        <div id="highlighter--hover-tools" style="display: none;">
            <div id="highlighter--hover-tools--container">
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-copy" title="Copy"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--separator"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-change-color" title="Change Color"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--separator"></div>
                <div class="highlighter--icon highlighter--icon-delete" title="Delete"></div>
            </div>
        </div></body>
</html>
```

---

Edit:
[image]

I am receiving an error in my console log

Comment: I did run your code and everything working fine . check your browser console for errors like CROS

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I really checked an figure out the warning shown there. I have added the screenshot of warnings here

Comment: it seems like your need to open your HTML file in a localhost environment like serve , nodejs , xampp or etc because when you drag or open this HTML file to the browser it loaded with file:// protocol and aframe can't load assets, etc with this protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to read the Aframe documentation before starting to work with it:

```
Use a Local Server
For the options below, we should develop projects using a local server so that files are properly served. Options of local servers include:

Downloading the Mongoose application and opening it from the same directory as your HTML file.
Running python -m SimpleHTTPServer (or python -m http.server for Python 3) in a terminal in the same directory as your HTML file.
Running npm install -g live-server && live-server in a terminal in the same directory as your HTML file.
Once we are running our server, we can open our project in the browser using the local URL and port which the server is running on (e.g., http://localhost:8000). Try not to open the project using the file:// protocol which does not provide a domain; absolute and relative URLs may not work.
```

Comment: But I am trying to use it in ASP.net core. Its already running the app on kesteral server.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your need to open your HTML file in a localhost environment like serve , nodejs , xampp or etc because when you drag or open this HTML file to the browser it loaded with file:// protocol and aframe can't load assets, etc with this protocol